# Nginx matches wrong domain

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Under the same server there's a few configuration blocks that look like so

```
server {
    server_name app.domain1.com;

    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    root /home/sites;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

        proxy_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
error_log /var/log/nginx/app-domain1.error_log notice;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     }
}
```

Only thing that changes is the server_name which goes like `app`, `preview`, `build` and of course the proxy_pass ip. This setup works just fine, but now a new domain was added using the same configuration, only difference is the server_name is now `app.domain2.com`. The dns for this points to the same ip as the previous domain. An ssl certificate was generated for `app.domain2.com` using certbot. Nginx doesn't match `app.domain2.com` rather it matches `app.domain1.com`. Same goes for any other prefix for `domain2`, it always matches `app.domain1.com`.

I tried adding a `default` configuration that includes both top level domains but no luck.

Using Cloudflare for DNS management, every entry is pointing to the server ip using the `DNS only` setting.

Any ideas?